# Docker volume on NFS share - empty directory

Tags: docker, nfs, share, nfs4

We have a Docker Swarm deployment running on two nodes (node1 and node2) for our business application.

The application needs a volume to store persistent data. As it is unclear where a container is deployed (node1 or node2) as well as maybe two containers of our application should run on both nodes we needed a solution to provide a shared volume for all nodes.

For sharing a volume we set up a NFS server on a third node3 with the following /etc/exports file:

```
/srv          *(rw,sync,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,all_squash,subtree_check,crossmnt,fsid=root)
```

(I use anonuid/gid to explicitly set for each files in the export the user information for a known user in the node3 system. all_squash is used to make sure all file rights from all accessing users are rewritten to this local user)

In our docker-compose.yml we use the following setup to include the volume:

```
volumes:
  nfs-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: nfsvers=4,addr=node3.example.com,rw,nolock,soft
```

We now ran into a problem where the the container just didn't want to start up, the error message was:

```
failed to copy file info for /var/lib/docker/volumes/MY_CONTAINER_nfs-data/_data: failed to chown /var/lib/docker/volumes/MY_CONTAINER_nfs-data/_data: lchown /var/lib/docker/volumes/MY_CONTAINER_nfs-data/_data: operation not permitted
```

After some digging around I found out that the problem relies in the initial empty folder on the exported NFS directory on the node3 server. As soon as I put in an empty file the startup of the container in node1 and node2 is working totally fine.

Does anyone has an explanation for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a named volume is initialized from an empty/new state, docker will copy the contents of the image directory into the named volume. There are several options to deal with this:

1. Initialize the named volume with content before the container starts. As you've seen, this disables the volume initialization step.
2. Update the image to have the desired uid/gid on the directory and contained files with a `RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /path`. This should prevent issues but you'll want to test to be sure there isn't still a chown trying to run from docker depending on how it initializes these files.
3. Disable squash on NFS. It's a common cause of issues with docker volumes, and I'm not sure what security benefit you get. If you really need to avoid root, you could try configuring docker with user namespacing, but this will break host volumes where you assume the uid matches, so be prepared for some effort.
4. Disable the volume initialization. With the [current compose spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3), there's a "nocopy" option you can add to your service volume spec using the long syntax. This is done on the service where the volume is used, not at the top level where the volume is defined.

The example from docker's documentation on the "nocopy" option looks like:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true

volumes:
  mydata:
```